# How was The Pirate Bay datacenter kept hidden?

Tags: dns, ip, geolocation, tracking

How were The Pirate Bay's servers kept hidden for so long? You would think that it would be easy finding the servers that so many DNS servers are pointing to. Tracing the chain to the main datacenter should have been an easy task, but why was it different in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pirate bay used multiple proxies around the world. As soon as one got detected, they switched over to another one. They used preinstalled encrypted images that they deployed at numerous cloud providers around the world. In order to stay hidden, the servers used many different techniques.

All traffic between the proxies and the main servers was tunneled through vpn connections. If a proxy lost contact with the main servers for 8 hours, it shut itself down. A fully encrypted, completely shut down server is probably never going to be decrypted without a key, if done right. The standard police method of taking computers, by unplugging the power to avoid shutdown scripts from running, ment that the in-memory key was lost as well.

On top of the proxies, they used cloudflare to hide the location of their proxies from the general public. The pirate bay DNS records still point to cloudflare today. Cloudflare is one of the companies that takes privacy really serious, defending the lulzsec black-hat hacker group's website from big DDOS attacks in 2011. Since cloudflare has support of automatic failover, a proxy being taken offline isn't a problem at all. When you are starting to run low on proxies, just spawn twenty new ones on other cloud providers, add them to the list and call it a day.

If you cannot ever read the configuration from a siezed server, and there's at least two levels of ever changing proxies in-between, there's not much you can do to find out where the backend servers are.

Answer (score 3):

> How were The Pirate Bay's servers kept hidden

One word: proxies. All you need is the Internet facing servers being fed from other servers, and all you can trace are the Internet facing ones.